# Adding rows to an empty typed DataFrame

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dataframe

Given a `@DataSchema` how do I go about creating an empty `DataFrame<MySchema>` and then adding rows?

I tried `val df = emptyDataFrame<MySchema>()` but `df.append(...)` results in an exception (division by zero) since the empty `df` has zero columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `emptyDataFrame<T>()` says:

```
 Returns [DataFrame] with no rows and no columns.
 To create [DataFrame] with empty columns or empty rows see [DataFrame.empty]
```

Essentially, this function creates a completely empty data frame which is just cast to your type. This explains why you cannot append values to it.

I think what you're looking for instead is the function `DataFrame.emptyOf<T>()`, whose docs says:

```
Creates a DataFrame with empty columns (rows = 0).
Can be used as a "null object" in aggregation operations, operations that work on columns (select, reorder, ...)
```

I created an [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/issues/463) on Github for these functions to be clarified/improved, because I understand the confusion they can cause.

Comment: You are right, `DataFrame.emptyOf<T>()` is the one I was looking for. In the API there are three paths to empty DataFrame (two of them immutable) which is a bit confusing: `DataFrame.emptyOf<T>`, `emptyDataFrame<T>` and `DataFrame.empty()`

Comment: ...and another one: `DataFrame.Empty`

Answer (score 0):

`emptyDataFrame()` returns an immutable, read-only `DataFrame` without any columns. I think there are multiple reasons you will not be able to append values to the dataframe.

1. [`emptyDataFrame()`](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/blob/0.8.0/core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/dataframe/api/constructors.kt#L294) calls [`DataFrame.empty()`](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/blob/0.8.0/core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/dataframe/DataFrame.kt#L30), which eventually calls `DataFrameImpl<Unit>(emptyList(), 0)`. The dataframe's columns are immutable, because `emptyList()` returns an immutable `List`.
2. [`append(values)`](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/blob/0.8.0/core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/dataframe/api/append.kt#L11) expects a [non-zero number of columns](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/blob/0.8.0/core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/dataframe/api/append.kt#L13). The dataframe was created with an empty list (0 columns), so `append` will fail. `ncol` is 0 because of the `emptyList()`, leading to the division by zero problem.

I have not used `kotlin-dataframe`, so there may be more issues. You might already know this, but for other readers: Kotlin is usually immutable by default.

To help you find a solution: Do you know which columns you intend to use when you create the dataframe? If yes, then it looks like there are [some constructors](https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/blob/80e346f2797cd6a27afe249cc9315dbaa9a9aaa6/core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/dataframe/api/constructors.kt) that would be more appropriate.